# A Result Concerning a 2012 Putnam Match Problem

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis

Problem B4 of 2012 Putnam Exam asks for proving the convergence of $a_n-\log n$, where $a_n$ is a sequence satisfying $$a_0=1, \, \, a_{n+1}=a_n+e^{-a_n}.$$ In  [the second solution of the problem](https://kskedlaya.org/putnam-archive/2012s.pdf), by taking $b_n=e^{a_n}$, one can conclude the inequality $$0\leq \frac {b_n}{n}-1\leq \frac{e}{n}+\frac{c\log n}{n} \, \, (*),$$ where the positive constant $c$ comes from a Taylor series for $e^{\frac{1}{b_n}}$ in the aforesaid solution. Now, my question is whether the argument above could be used to prove that the sequence $$e^{a_n}-n-\frac{1}{2}\log n$$ is convergent, or essentially is that a true claim? I could not deduce this from the situation of $e^{a_n}-n-c\log n$. Any help or suggestion would be thanked in advance.

Answer (score 3):

$e^{a_n}-n-c\log n$  and $e^{a_n}-n-\frac 1  2\log n$ cannot both be convergent since their differece does not converge (because $c \neq \frac 1  2$.)